Receiving "RESULT_CANCELED" Result from request.show() when using Google Play Billing API in TWA
I'm attempting to use the Google Play Billing API in a TWA and am testing on a Closed Release version of the app on a physical device. It's been an absolute nightmare from step 1 but I'm trying to comply with Google policy before I deploy the application publicly.
I'm initiating Google Play Billing in my TWA using the code below -


async function initiateGPay() {
    if('getDigitalGoodsService' in window) {
        try {
            const service = await window.getDigitalGoodsService('https://play.google.com/billing')
            const skuDetails = await service.getDetails(['donator_pack_1', 'donator_pack_2', 'donator_pack_3', 'donator_pack_5', 'donator_pack_10', 'donator_pack_20', 'monthly-plan'])

            if(skuDetails) {
                $(".paypalBuyContainer").addClass("d-none")
                $(".googleBuyContainer").removeClass("d-none")
            } else {
                return;
            }
            
            $(".googleBuyButton").each((i, el) => {
                let sku = skuDetails.find(sku => sku.itemId == el.getAttribute("sku"))
                if(!sku) {
                    console.error("Failed to retrieve SKU " + el.getAttribute("sku"))
                    return;
                }
                $(el).on("click", async ev => {
                    await this.makePurchase(service, sku);
                })
            })
        } catch (error) {
            // Google Play billing not available
            console.log(error)
            return;
        }
    }
}



So far this works and I correctly get the SKU details  and assign a click handler to my multiple purchase buttons. When a button is clicked I then call 'makePurchase' and pass the established service and the relevant SKU. This fails at the await request.show() part.


async function makePurchase(service, sku) {
    // Define the preferred payment method and item ID
    const paymentMethods = [{
        supportedMethods: "https://play.google.com/billing",
        data: {
            sku: sku,
        }
    }];

    const paymentDetails = {
        total: {
            label: `Total`,
            amount: {currency: `GBP`, value: `0`}
        }
    };

    const request = new PaymentRequest(paymentMethods, paymentDetails);
    try {
        const paymentResponse = await request.show();
        const {purchaseToken} = paymentResponse.details;
    
        // Call backend to validate and acknowledge the purchase.
        if (await acknowledgePurchaseOnBackend(purchaseToken, sku)) {
            service.consume(purchaseToken);
            
            // Optional: tell the PaymentRequest API the validation was
            // successful. The user-agent may show a "payment successful"
            // message to the user.
            const paymentComplete = await paymentResponse.complete('success');
        } else {
            // Optional: tell the PaymentRequest API the validation failed. The
            // user agent may show a message to the user.
            const paymentComplete = await paymentResponse.complete('fail');
        }
    } catch(e) {
        // The purchase failed, and we can handle the failure here. AbortError
        // usually means a user cancellation
        console.error(e)
    }
    
}



Where it gets somewhat interesting is the nonsense error messages I'm receiving in the console that appears to have a reference to Facebook despite there being no references in either my TWA or my website itself -

Donator:1 No "Link: rel=payment-method-manifest" HTTP header found at "https://www.facebook.com/pay".


donator.js?v=1.0.8:134 DOMException: Payment app returned RESULT_CANCELED code. This is how payment apps can close their activity programmatically.

